# CSS: Change Headlinecolor in Menu

Tags: css

I have the following problem:

In my menu (Backlinks > Our Bestsellers) there is a heading. I would like to make it white. But the class

"mega-block-title" wont change anything.

I tried:

```css
.mega-block-title {
    color: #ffffff
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short dirty solution use `!important`.

```
.mega-block-title {
   color: white !important;
}
```

To do it cleaner you should see where the color of that element gets set, and change it, or add a class to that element and override that property. It depends by how the color gets defined now...

If you do right click to on that element and do "Inspect Element" you'll see these CSS properties:

```
#mega-menu-wrap-primary #mega-menu-primary > li.mega-menu-megamenu > ul.mega-sub-menu > li.mega-menu-item h4.mega-block-title, #mega-menu-wrap-primary #mega-menu-primary > li.mega-menu-megamenu > ul.mega-sub-menu li.mega-menu-column > ul.mega-sub-menu > li.mega-menu-item h4.mega-block-title {
    color: #555;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding: 0px 0px 5px 0px;
    vertical-align: top;
    display: block;
    visibility: inherit;
    border: 0;
}
```

If you find out where that `color: #555` gets defined you can edit it, but then it could affect other elements too... I don't know if you want that...

if you want only that title to be white you need to add a class like

```
<h4 class="mega-block-title is-white">Unsere Bestseller:</h4>
```

and then in CSS do

```
#mega-menu-wrap-primary #mega-menu-primary > li.mega-menu-megamenu > ul.mega-sub-menu > li.mega-menu-item h4.mega-block-title, #mega-menu-wrap-primary #mega-menu-primary > li.mega-menu-megamenu > ul.mega-sub-menu li.mega-menu-column > ul.mega-sub-menu > li.mega-menu-item h4.mega-block-title.is-white {
    color: white;
}
```